# Whats the use of calling a fn in resolved promise?

Tags: javascript

I have seen people doing this:

`Promise.resolve().then(fn)`

in many places and makes me wonder why this is the case? Why can't they call `fn` directly? Why to resolve a `Promise` and then call a `fn`?

Comment: Because the result of the promise can only be used after it's resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do this in a couple of situations:

1. You need to return/provide a promise. `fn()` would result in the return value of `fn` (or `undefined` if it doesn't specify one). But `Promise.resolve().then(fn)` results in a promise. (Granted, though, if they just wanted a promise, they could do `Promise.resolve(fn())`.)
2. You need to ensure the call to `fn` happens asynchronously (since promise `then`/`catch`/`finally` callbacks are asynchronous¹).

---

¹ Specifically, they're run as *microtasks* run after the end of the *macrotask* in which they were queued. JavaScript works by processing a job queue, aka a task queue. On browsers, a "macrotask" is what we're used to thinking of as calls to JavaScript from the browser: The main script run, event handlers, the callbacks for timers, etc. Any "microtasks" scheduled during a macrotask are run, in order, just after the end of the current macrotask but before the next macrotask (even if it was schedule before they microtask was). Many other environments (such as Node.js) behave similarly.

Comment: Thanks. Point 2 is really helpful!

Comment: @batman - Yeah, I realized at one point (see edit) that point 1 is a bit weak, you could just do `Promise.resolve(fn())`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because.. They want to perform some task either when the promise has resolved or when the promise has resolved and brought some data with it, then you can use the returned data.

A promise could be from an API request which may take some time to resolve, you want to act upon the returned data.. so what will you do??

```
Promise.resolve().then((data) => {
   // now act upon the data..
})
```